# What do you call metal stuffs embedded onto clothing?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call metal stuffs embedded onto clothing? It can be gold, silver or even plastic or other non-metal. What do you call these things embedded into clothing?

Comment: The things on the mask are [studs](https://bellatory.com/clothing/Stud-Everything-A-DIY-guide-to-studding)

Comment: is there a more general term?

Comment: Do you know a 'more general' way of attaching metal to fabric than as studs?

Comment: You should answer the question so I can accept your answer.

Comment: OP may be thinking of "Embossing", "Beading", "Sequin", "Spangle", or something similar? This link guides one through the many possible ways of accessorizing fabrics. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/accessories-and-decorations-on-clothes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be thinking of "Embossing", "Beading", "Sequin", "Spangle", or something similar? This link guides one through the many possible ways of accessorizing fabrics.
I would think this is an example of "Spangle", as it seems to involve small shiny pieces of metal or plastic used for decorating clothes, but the pieces do *not* penetrate the cloth, thus not studs.

There is a unique word for each and every means of accessorizing or decorating a piece of clothing.

Here is a link to a reasonably comprehensive guide.
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/accessories-and-decorations-on-clothes

Answer (score 1):

The metallic objects attached to the mask in the picture are *studs.*

Comment: For those to be "studs", they would need to be piercing through the fabric. To my eye, they seem to be glued on instead. That would make them "Sequins", or (being metallic and glittery), "Spangles"